# Why does jQuery .html() not use utf-8?

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, utf-8, cheerio

I'm scraping some data from a website (with NodeJS, cheerio and request) and got the following problem:
One div has an address in it like this:

```
Examplestreet 20
<br>
8490 Zürich
```

When I get the div with `$('.div').text()` the output is `Examplestreet208490 Zürich`. So to get that linebreak aswell I do it like this `$('.div').html()`. But now the output is `Examplestreet 20<br>8490 Z&#xFC;rich`.

So why does .html() not use utf-8?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. For me, `html()` returns UTF-8 string as expected if I use `console.log()` as the output.

Comment: @Genhis I think the problem is the website where I try to scrape the data from. Normally .html() returns an UTF-8 string, yes.

Comment: There's confusion about what the "&#xFC;" is, that's called a html entity. It's not the ü in a weird encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why this problem occured, but I solved it by creating two seperate values for the text before the `<br>` and the text after it. Like this:

```
$('.div').get(0).firstChild.data                   // for the text before
$('.div').children('br').get(0).nextSibling.data   // for the text after
```

This may be shabby, but it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

use `innerText`, which maintain the text appearance - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText

> Basically, innerText is aware of the rendered appearance of text

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('div').innerText);
```

```html
<div>
  Examplestreet 20<br><br><br><br>8490 Zürich
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since cheerio is jQuery based I can't use this with my selector. When I try to use `document.querySelector('.mySelector').innerText` I get `document is not defined` :/